# How to use href to to submit form and send hidden values to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have a list displays jobs in my view,when I click that link it should take me to different page to display complete details and in the browser url is should display like below

//mysite.com/jobs/auto-damage-adjuster-trainee-houston-and-surrounding-cities.

To achieve this I am trying to submit form on click and pass hidden value to controller.But it Always passes first item from the list.

```
@model List<JobPortal.Models.MyDB>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Current List";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@foreach (var list in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="flexcontainer">
            @Html.Partial("_MySharedView", list)
        </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

Shared View -

```
@model JobPortal.Models.MyDB
@if (Model.JDetails.Count > 0)
{
   @foreach (var item in JDetails)
{

<form id="Jobs" action="~/Jobs?id=@Model.id" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value=@Model.id />
    <strong><a href="~/Jobs?@Model.title" onclick="document.getElementById('Jobs').submit();">@Model.title</a></strong>
</form>
}
}
```

Controller -

```
public ActionResult Jobs(int? id)
{
    var allDetails = _db.MyDB.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(allDetails);
}
```

How do I submit form onclick href and pass hidden value to controller?

Comment: It is mandatory to use a POST method instead of a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An id attribute's value should only ever be assigned to one html element. The onclick handler for the form will only ever find the first id because they're designed to be unique. Instead you should append something unique to the id on the form element in your example so that they're all unique. For example:

```
<form id="Jobs-@item.id" action="~/Jobs?id=@item.id" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value=@item.id />
    <strong><a href="~/Jobs?@item.title" onclick="document.getElementById('Jobs-@item.id').submit();">@item.title</a></strong>
</form>
```

Edit: You should definitely be using an identifier on each item to distinguish between each form block and each input.